# Why pidof and pgrep are behaving differently?

Tags: grep, process, init-script, pidof

I have a init script in `/etc/init.d/myservice` for initialize a service like this:

```
...
start() {
  ...
  daemon /usr/sbin/myservice
  ...
}

stop() {
  ...
  pgrep myservice
  pidof myservice
  ps -ef | grep myservice
  ...
}
```

And when I try to stop the service, this is the output:

```
10000 10001
10000
root      10000     1  0 09:52 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/myservice
root      9791   9788  0 10:06 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /sbin/service myservice stop
root      10001  9791  1 10:06 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/init.d/myservice stop 
root      9805   9796  0 10:06 pts/1    00:00:00 grep myservice
```

Is this expected? Why `pidof` is returning only the correct PID of the service that I want to stop and `pgrep` is returning the service PID and the PID of the init script? Can I rely on that `pidof` will always ignore the PID from the init script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pidof = find the process ID of a running program

Pidof finds the process id's (pids) of the named programs.  It  prints
   those  id's  on  the  standard output. This program is on some systems
   used in run-level change scripts, especially when  the  system  has  a
   System-V  like rc structure.

```
sysadmin@codewarden:~$ pidof apache2
5098 5095 5094 5092
```

pgrep = look  up or signal processes based on name and other attributes,
         pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the
       process IDs which matches the selection criteria.

```
sysadmin@codewarden:~$ pgrep apache2
5092
5094
5095
5098
```

`pgrep`, (p) = process, `grep` = grep prints the matching lines

Want to know more about pgrep & pidof ?
Just run in terminal as

```
# man pidof
# man pgrep
```

Comment: Aha, that is why `pidof` is not returning `10001`, because the program is `sh`, no?

Comment: yeap, you right

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't rely on `pidof`, it can cause your program to fail. A simple example with `supervisord` program:

```
% cuonglm at ~
% ps -ef | grep supervisord
root      8512     1  0 16:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
cuonglm   8584  7688  0 17:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto supervisord
% cuonglm at ~
% pidof supervisord
% cuonglm at ~
%
```

You can see, the `supervisord` is actually called by python interpreter, causes `pidof` to fail:

```
#! /usr/bin/python                                                            
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'supervisor==3.0a8','console_scripts','supervisord'
__requires__ = 'supervisor==3.0a8'                                            
import sys                                                                    
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point                                    

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                    
    sys.exit(                                                                 
        load_entry_point('supervisor==3.0a8', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
    )
```

Comment: But in this case I can rely on it no?, I am not using an interpreter to execute the program (it is a executable binary).

Comment: Of course. But I think the good way is use `killproc`. Why you don't use this while you haved used `daemon` in `start` function?

Comment: Because I want to get the PID to kill the children of the process, I was using `killproc` to kill the process itself.

Comment: Why must you do that? if you kill `parent process`, its `child process` will died, too.

Comment: No, I don't think so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533377/why-child-process-still-alive-after-parent-process-was-killed-in-linux

Comment: Just pass signal `-9` to `killproc`.

Comment: The `-9` is too aggressive for me :D

Answer (score 0):

The `pidof` command ignores scripts unless you include the `-x` option.
Also, it is safest to include the full path on the pidof command, as in:

```
killme=$(pidof -x /usr/bin/supervisord)
      *instead of*
killme=$(pidof -x supervisord)
```

this minimizes the chances of matching some other process.